# Use pry-rescue In a rake Task?

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm trying to use [pry-rescue](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue) inside of a rake task. Something like this:

```
   bundle exec rescue rake my:task
```

But when an exception occurs (`undefined method...`) it just exists like normal. **How can I use pry-rescue with my rake task?**

Comment: Open issue on github:  https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue/issues/74

Answer (score 6):

Did you try wrapping your task body in a rescue block?

```
task 'my_task' do
  Pry.rescue {
    things.that_need_doing
  }
end
```